# Como usar o th:each de modo a combinar linhas com colunas?

Tags: thymeleaf

Preciso carregar uma lista de receitas no meu site de modo que fique 3 receitas por linha (row). Estou usando th:each para exibir as receitas. Segue o código:

```
<div th:each="receita : ${receitas}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card card-style col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${receita.nome}"></h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${receita.preparo}"></p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Veja mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

porém dessa maneira é gerado uma abaixo da outra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu tento colocar mais cards dentro da row desta maneira:

```
<div th:each="receita : ${receitas}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card card-style col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${receita.nome}"></h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${receita.preparo}"></p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Veja mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card-style col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${receita.nome}"> 
            </h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${receita.preparo}"> 
            </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Veja mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card-style col-sm-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${receita.nome}"> 
            </h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${receita.preparo}"> 
            </p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Veja mais</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Ele funciona apenas se vier 3 receitas, pois se vier 1, ele irá duplicar os dados nos 3 cards.

Como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Se tu quer deixar um espaço entre elas (e deixar uma embaixo da outra), coloque o espaçamento na `div` do `foreach`: `<div class="col-sm-3" th:each="receita : ${receitas}">`

Comment: Gostaria que fiquem uma do lado da outra, sendo 3 por linha

Comment: Aqui tem a lógica em PHP, no caso, vai ter que declarar uma variável com o número de colunas por linha (no teu caso seria `$bootstrapColWidth=4`). No fim do foreach, tem que verificar se o index é divisível por 3, se for, adiciona mais uma `row`, assim tu vai ter sempre 3 elementos por linha. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561301/loop-row-in-bootstrap-every-3-columns